# Update filter result after outside controller val has been change

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-filters

I have a service which controls the general settings of the user.

One of the settings is a global time format for dates. 
For example - If the user has selected U.S Format, all the times that is being presented to the user should be in the format of AM PM, otherwise, it will present 24 hour time.

*
 * Set the global user settings
 */

```
app.factory('UserSettings', ['localStorageService', function (localStorageService) {

    var UserSettings = {};

    /**
     * The user settings
     * @type {}
     */
    var userSettings = null;

    /**
     * The user settings key for the local storage
     * @type {string}
     */
    var userSettingsKey = 'userSettings';

    /**
     * Get the user settings
     * Timeformat - 1 = international
     * Timeformat - 2 = U.S
     * @return {Object}
     */
    UserSettings.getUserSettings = function () {
        if (!userSettings) {
            userSettings = localStorageService.get(userSettingsKey);
            if (!userSettings)
            //Default user settings
                userSettings = {timeFormat: 1}
        }
        return userSettings;
    };

    /**
     * Set the user settings object in the scope and in the local storage
     * @param {Object}
     */
    UserSettings.setUserSettings = function (settings) {
        if (settings) {
            var success = localStorageService.set(userSettingsKey, settings);
            if (success)
                userSettings = settings;
            return success;
        }
    };

    return UserSettings;

}]);
```

The selected format is being activated inside a filter

> timeFormatFilter

```
/**
 * Get a formatted text from timestemp
 * It will return the time in the format that was set inside the UserSettings
 */
app.filter('timeFormatFilter', ['UserSettings', function (UserSettings) {
    var userSettings;
    /**
     * @param time The time
     * @param isDate if to return a string with a date
     * @param isTime if to return a string with a time
     */
    return function (time, isDate, isTime) {
        var formattedTime = '';

        if (!time)
            return formattedTime;
        userSettings = UserSettings.getUserSettings();

        var utcTime = moment(time).utc();

        if (isDate)
            formattedTime = formattedTime + getDate(utcTime) + ' ';
        if (isTime)
            formattedTime = formattedTime + getTime(utcTime);

        return formattedTime;
    };

    /**
     * Get a date string in the format that is set inside the UserSettings
     * @param utcTime
     * @returns {string}
     */
    function getDate(utcTime) {
        var date = '';

        switch (userSettings.timeFormat) {
            case 1:
                date = utcTime.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
                break;
            case 2:
                date = utcTime.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                break;
        }
        return date;

    }

    /**
     * Get a time string in the format that is set inside the UserSettings
     * @param utcTime
     * @returns {string}
     */
    function getTime(utcTime) {
        var time = '';
        switch (userSettings.timeFormat) {
            case 1:
                time = utcTime.format('HH:mm');
                break;
            case 2:
                time = utcTime.format('h:mm a');
                break;
        }
        return time;
    }
}]);
```

The HTML:

```
 {{startTime| timeFormatFilter:true:false}}
```

The process is working fine, but the filter is not recalled after the UserSettings is being changed. I want to bind somehow the filter fire to the changes of the UserSettings.

I saw some questions over here but none of them answered my question.

Comment: I assume your filter works only first time when you run the application. Have you tried to use a $watch over UserSettings?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I thought of it, but I don't know what to write in listening function. If the UserSettings changes, and a listening function is being called, how do I tell the dom that it needs to reFire the filter function
?

Comment: I tried to $rootscope.$apply to refresh the dom but it didn't worked